# How can I show a board description

Tags: trello

Sure, members can see the description if they click to edit the board title, but otherwise, how can they see it?  I'd like the description to be visible whenever someone is in the board. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware you can't do this, just as you can't make a card's description visible by default.
This is probably due to the extra space that may be required since a description can be quite long.